# Spark - Find most common words in dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset below like:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|prediction|text                                                                         |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1         |this is a important sentence important sentence                              |
|2         |this is a simple sentence, simple sentence and important sentence]           |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to find the most common N-words in each row (for example top 2 words).
Example:

- In row 1 most common words are "important" and "sentence".
- In row 2 most common words are "simple" and "sentence".

Finally make a new Dataset should look like below :

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|prediction|text                                                                         | top terms
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|1         |this is a important sentence important sentence                              | important,sentence
|2         |this is a simple sentence, simple sentence and important sentence]           | simple,sentence
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Please show me a piece of code to solve it, I worked with java but the language you use does not matter because I'll converting it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# regex remove all nonalphanumeric characters, split by " " and explode words
# count each value group by 'prediction' and word
# add row number descending for counted words in each 'prediction'
# filter/select only top 2 words
# collect top terms to array using collect_list
# concat list values using array_join to return string

df.select('*,explode(split(regexp_replace('text,"[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]","")," ")).as("val"))
.groupBy('prediction,'val,'text)
.agg(count('val).as("val_cnt"))
.select('*,row_number.over(Window.partitionBy("prediction").orderBy('val_cnt.desc)).as("row_number"))
.where('row_number<=2)
.select('prediction,'text,'val)
.groupBy('prediction,'text).agg(collect_list('val).as("topterms"))
.select('prediction,'text,array_join('topterms,",").as("top_terms"))
.show(false)
```

output:

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|prediction|text                                                              |top_terms         |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|1         |this is a important sentence important sentence                   |sentence,important|
|2         |this is a simple sentence, simple sentence and important sentence]|sentence,simple   |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to words for each  prediction show in the same row like my post example

Comment: @merchantappsep  I added some changes